# multiple float input() with for loop value

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, floating-point, user-input

I am trying get floating point number from  user input with for loop in python 3.6.7:

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
     foo = float(input())

Input:
      1
      12.3
```

No error, But when it is more than one value Error shows up:

```
for _ in range(int(input())):
     foo = float(input())

 Input:
      2
      2.5 3.1

ValueError: Could not convert string to float: '2.5 3.1'
```

any thoughts? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you input something and press Enter, `input` treats that data as a *single string*. So, `3.141<hit Enter>` is a single string `"3.141"`, and it can be converted to a floating-point number with `float`.

However, `3.141 5926<hit Enter here>` is a *single string* `"3.141 5926"`. Is that a representation of *a single (floating-point) number*? It's not (there are *two* numbers), so `float` can't convert that to a *single* number because of the space.

If you want to treat these numbers separated by a space as individual numbers, `split` the string and then convert each number:

```
data = input().split() # gives ['3.141', '5926']
for x in data:
    print(float(x)) # converts each string to a number
```